# Update xlim based on current ylim?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, rescale

I have a plot in matplotlib and I would like to resize automatically the `xlim` based on the view fixed by `ylim`. How to do that ?

Currently I write :

```
plt.ylim(0, 10)
```

And the problem occurs when I have a set of data that goes from `y=0` to `y=20`, then the `xlim` remain unchanged : I would like to have it automatically rescaled for the view corresponding to `plt.ylim(0, 10)`.

Comment: Can you write a wrapper function that modifies both xlim and ylim at the same time?  Even more radically you could try to patch in a version of ylim that did this.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Can you clarify it a bit more, maybe with an example? You may find the get_ylim() method of the axes instance useful.

Comment: Exactly Thom, `ax.set_xlim(ax.get_ylim())` would do the trick.

Comment: @RutgerKassies: that does the trick only if you plot `y=x`. The question is about an automatic way to get `xlim` adjusted according to what is shown in the figure